# Does compiling make my sensitive data safe?

Tags: c#, json, compilation, passwords

Kind of a quick question here, couldn't find the answer on-line.. and that could well be because it's a strange question.

I want to send data (basically strings/JSON) through a port that I have listening on a Linux server from a C# application. When the application talks to the server for the first time it must pass the correct credentials which are obviously meant to be secret. So when I compile this application are these credentials (username/password combo) safe? I guess not because I have heard of decompilers and the like. So in what way would you make this safe? Surely any application that has been compiled and connects to a public database or something similar must have the details stored in the executable somewhere.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here, sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: Most applications pass data to an application on the server, then that application interacts with the database.

Comment: Absolutely not. Not even a little bit safe.

Comment: Even obfuscation is a joke.. so don't bother looking that up if you're really worried about code security.

Comment: Try out the tool [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) (a very useful freeware tool) and have a look at your "compiled" assembly. DotNet does not compile your source to machine code it uses an intermediate language, this language can be reverted to all flavors of DotNet (CSharp, VB, ...), you even can find your comments there.

Comment: @howderek - In that case what would stop anyone sending information down that port to the server application?

Comment: You can't prevent that. To the server the requests will look the same, but at least that way your client code will never touch the database. Possibly having people interact with a web application using a different client (like other launchers for Minecraft) isn't nearly as much of a security issue as having a client directly edit a database.

Comment: I would also like to point out that regardless of how well you hide network code in your application, people can see what you send to a server with deep packet inspection tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not.

Broadly put, you can't ever assume that any data you ship to an end user in any form will be safe from prying eyes of some sort.

What are you trying to do in the first place? What are the security requirements?

Comment: I have a application listening to a port on a Linux server. So I need to authenticate with the client app before allowing anything else through the socket. In that case I'd need to send over a username and password or something, therefor I guess I'd need that stored in the code so it knows what to send..?

Comment: That is indeed the case. And now you know it's also not secure. :)

Comment: OK, my heads spinning now lol. So what IS the secure way of doing this, like.. How does commercial software do this?

Comment: I'm still not sure what your actual security requirements are. Do you want to make sure no one can eavesdrop (MITM) the traffic? Do you want to make sure the client is communicating with your server and nothing else? Do you want to make sure only your client, and not a custom one written by an enterprising end-user, can communicate with your server? Etc.

Comment: My main requirement is your last statement, to only allow my client applications to interact with the server.

Comment: Then I'd say you're out of luck, as a skilled programmer can reverse-engineer your client and write something to emulate its behavior, and you'll be left playing a cat-and-mouse game of changing/obfuscating your protocol. For a prominent-ish example of this sort of thing, see the Despotify library for Spotify. http://despotify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That's pretty scary! So what about something like world of warcraft, or other client rpgs. If someone "reverse engineered" that and made their own program to send exp updates to their character every 5 minutes then that would be a pretty unfair advantage!

Comment: The XP updates, etc. happen and are validated on the server. The client is restricted to doing only things they could naturally do (ie. move, cast spells/use actions, chat, `/dance` of course, ...). In addition, WoW uses this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warden_(software)

Comment: So basically, there is only the "manual approach", where everything that happens must be strictly validated. I guess that answers my question, thank you for keeping with me!

Comment: Indeed. Never trust client input. :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For the application you have described, you should probably put the credentials in a file and set the permissions such that only the immediate owner can read the file. I would never recommend putting sensitive information into a file that anyone else can read, such as your application.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are reflection tools that can show the code in your application. You can use tools that "scramble" your code (through obfuscation) and that can be somewhat effective, although not 100% secure

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 2.0 introduced a new feature, called protected configuration, that enables you to encrypt sensitive information in a configuration file. Although primarily designed for ASP.NET, protected configuration can also be used to encrypt configuration file sections in Windows applications. For a detailed description of the protected configuration capabilities, see [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Which doesn't help at all, because if the application is able to somehow read the configuration, then another application is, too.